# interior boundaries and closures

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Let $X = \{a,b,c,d,e\}$ where the $5$ elements are all different. Let $T = \bigl\{X, \emptyset,\{a\},\{a,b\},\{a,c,d\},\{a,b,c,d\},\{a,b,e\}\bigr\}$. Is $T$ a topology on $X$? List all the closed subsets of $X$. Determine the closures of $\{a\},\{b\},$ and $\{a,e\}.$ Also find the interior of those three sets and their boundaries.

Here is what I know:

I know $T$ is a topology on $X$.

I know the closed subsets of $X$ are $X, \emptyset, \{b,c,d,e\},\{c,d,e\},\{b,e\},\{e\},\{c,d\}$.

What is the interior of $\{b\}$ though? I know for the closure the complement has to be open. I was also thinking that the the boundary would be the closure minus the interior. Can someone please show how they would get the interior? I am still not sure about the working.

Comment: I understand the boundaries. What about the interior and the closures. For instance, would {b}={b,c,d,e} for closure. I am still not sure about the interior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at one example to see how this works. Take $\{a,e\}$. The interior is the union of all open sets inside of it, so perusing the list of open sets, the only such open sets are $\emptyset$ and $\{a\}$. So the interior is $\{a\}$. The closure is the intersection of all closed sets containing $\{a,e\}$. Looking at your list of closed sets, which I am assuming is accurate, the only one containing $\{a,e\}$ is $X$ itself. Thus the closure is all of $X$. Finally the boundary is defined to be the closure minus the interior. So in this case, it is $X\setminus\{a\}=\{b,c,d,e\}$.You can do the other sets similarly.

Comment: I get the boundary definition. I am still having trouble with the interior and closure definition though. Can you show me how you would work this out please? I know I can do the rest if I see this?

Comment: I am assuming that the closure of {a} would be x too. What about {b}? Would that be {d,c,d,e}

Comment: @user99744 The closure of $\{b\}$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing it. This is $X\cap\{b,c,d,e\}\cap\{b,e\}=\{b,e\}$.

Comment: Thanks I figured that one out when it comes to closure and boundaries. Still not sure about the interior. It is giving me trouble.

Comment: Why would int{a,e}={a} and not {e} can you show this to me. It is starting to become a little clearer with your explanations

Comment: @user99744: Note that $\{e\}$ is not open. The interior is the largest open set inside of $\{a,e\}$.

Comment: So I suppose that int{a}={a}. Still confused about int{b}. Would that just be {b}. Or is it $\emptyset$ because in $T$ $=$ {a,c,d} does not contain contain {b} in it?

Comment: The interior of $\{b\}$ is empty since the only open set inside of it is the emptyset.

Comment: Ok. I see now. Thanks for the help. I just needed some clarification and you helped me with it. Thank you again!

Comment: @user99744: You are welcome!